# PHP get category and id from csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv, categories

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
CategoryA;ID0001;title1
CategoryA;ID0002;title2
CategoryB;ID0001;title3
CategoryB;ID0002;title4
CategoryC;ID0001;title5

[More categories, IDs and titles...]
```

In order to sort these entries by category and the respective IDs within each category, I need at least two nested arrays. The first one with the categories and a key like "cat" and the second one with the IDs having a key like "id".

My awful attempt on this:

```
function read_csv($filename)
{
    $rows = [];

    foreach (file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $line) {
        $rows[] = str_getcsv($line, ';');
    };

    return $rows;
};

print_r(read_csv("file.csv"));
```

Resulting in this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 0001
            [2] => titel1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => 0002
            [2] => titel2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => 0001
            [2] => titel3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => 0002
            [2] => titel4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => 0001
            [2] => titel5
        )

)
```

Or is there a way to rename the keys? Everything I tried so far did not yield the expected result. How should I proceed?

Comment: could be worth loading in to a db, even a temp table

Comment: There's a number of csv parsers available on GitHub and I'm pretty sure php has its own inbuilt class for csv parsing. Try that? Otherwise `$rows[]` should be changed to include the column header (I.e. `$rows[$column]`) and however you've extracted the column name

Comment: @Dagon if it's just a quick script to do a specific purpose, it's not worth the overhead of setting up a sql db but long term, possibly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need a database, even a simple one like SQLite.  But for fun,  you can construct the CSV array with column names:

```
$cols = array('cat', 'id', 'title');

foreach (file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $line){
    $rows[] = array_combine($cols, str_getcsv($line, ';'));
}
```

Then you can use `array_column()` and sort with [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
array_multisort(array_column($rows, 'cat'),  $rows);
```

Or maybe:

```
array_multisort(array_column($rows, 'cat'), array_column($rows, 'id'), $rows);
```

Without the column names you can still use the numeric index:

```
array_multisort(array_column($rows, 0), array_column($rows, 1), $rows);
```

Comment: That really helps, but is still not what I wanted to do.
I should have been a bit more explicit, but whatsoever: I'm gonna see what I can do with it.
Thank you.